# How can I copy data from an xml file into another xml file using xsl at a specified location

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to copy data from file1 to file2 using xsl transformation. I am able to copy the data, but not at the location I desire. Please help me have the data copied to the right place. Here is my code:

file1.xml:

```
<Org>
    <Department name="Environmental" />
</Org>
```

file2.xml:

```
<Org>
    <Division>Engineering</Division>
    <Address>123 Elm Street</Address>
</Org>
```

result.xml:

```
<Org>
    <Division>Engineering</Division>
    <Address>123 Elm Street</Address>

</Org>
    <Department name="Environmental" />
```

Desired output:

```
<Org>
    <Department name="Environmental">
        <Division>Engineering</Division>
        <Address>123 Elm Street</Address>
    </Department>
</Org>
```

Here is the code from my xsl file:

```
  <xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='Org'][*[local-name()='Department']]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="document($lookup)/Agency/Division" />
                    <xsl:copy-of select="document($lookup)//Agency/Address" />
                </xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
```

Can somebody please help me in fixing the issue.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your XSLT template to the following. The variable `lookup` should contain the filename and path of `file2.xml`.

```
<!-- Copies the 'Org' node of file1.xml and applies the templates on the child elements -->
<xsl:template match="/*[local-name()='Org']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Copies the 'Department' node of file1.xml and then includes the values from file2.xml (in $lookup variable) -->
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Department' and parent::*[local-name()='Org']]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />              <!-- Copy the @name attribute (and possible others) -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="document($lookup)/Org/Division" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="document($lookup)/Org/Address" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />  
  </xsl:copy>     
</xsl:template>
```

The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Org>
    <Department name="Environmental">
        <Division>Engineering</Division>
        <Address>123 Elm Street</Address>
    </Department>
</Org>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I forgot to mention one thing in my original post. The xml  has Department as Child for Org and Agency as well. I only need the Division and Address copied to the Department that is a Child to Org and not Agency. The above transformation copies the Division, Address data to all the Department nodes.

Comment: @iranichai: I added a fix that (possibly) solved the problem. If that does not what you want, I'd probably need more information.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. It solved the problem.

Comment: When I put this to work, I see a nested 'Department' element getting created. How can I have just one parent Department with 'Division' and 'Address' as children. Below is the output I see:
<Department>
    <Department name="Environmental">
        <Division>Engineering</Division>
        <Address>123 Elm Street</Address>
    </Department>
</Department>

Thanks.

Comment: A new problem? By looking at the code I can only suspect that you have a nested `Org/Department` structure in your XML. But please don't modify this question, it's against the rules of SO and would mess everything up. Rather ask a new question with the new situation.

Comment: You can try to change the first line of the second template to `<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Org']/*[local-name()='Department']">`, but that is essentially the same.